# Eclipse only with keyboard

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to be more productive with eclipse in Linux by using just the keyboard. I find relatively easy to use the shortcuts, but I struggle with popup windows. For example, when creating getters and setters, I have to press Shift + Alt + S, R, and then I have a lot of keys to access each option. Nonetheless, when I want to close the window (Accept) it seems I have to traverse all controls using Tab. Is it the case? Is there a easier way?

Thank you all

Comment: The characters are underlined which can be used to directly access the function via Alt+<key>. In your case, e.g. press Alt+A to select *a*ll getters and setters.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the buttons Accept, Close, Apply & Close do not have a underlined character. My problem is there: I can access all options using Alt + <char> but I cannot Accept or Close using the keyboard (except traversing all controls using Tab). Btw, sorry about my english, I'm from Spain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the focus is not on a button you can use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to apply and close the dialog.

For canceling the operation hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which also closes the dialog.

Comment: Thank you. That will have to do. It's certainly better than pressing Tab repeatedly until the button is focused.